# How can I configure WCF activity propagation without a config file?

Tags: c#, wcf, trace

I have a self-hosted WCF service that uses [activity IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.currentthreadactivityid(v=vs.110).aspx) for logging purposes. I want to have the service activity ID match what is set on the client. This is the property I use in my service method to get the client's activity ID:

```
Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId
```

This is the configuration I have, in both the service and the client:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" ... propagateActivity="true">
...
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Without this configuration, `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` returns an empty GUID.

How can I accomplish the same thing without the configuration, i.e. entirely in C#? I have access to both service and client code. Is there a setting somewhere that I can set to enable activity propagation over WCF?

Comment: The namespace System.Diagnostics.Trace has some configurations for Diagnostics, maybe you can find something to reach the goal.
See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983739(v=vs.71).aspx